# Set Label on view dismiss - xCode storyboard

Tags: iphone, xcode, storyboard, viewcontroller

I use the storyboard seque to modal a UIViewController over my tabbarController. The purpose of the view controller that pops up is to take a few user inputs and return an answer to a label on one of the tab bar views (the one that was selected before the view controller popped up).

In my code I added `#import "viewBeforePopup.h"` to the poppedUpView.h header file.

Then I create an outlet

```
IBOutlet viewBeforePopup *view;
```

The button that triggers the view controller dismal has this code associated with it

---

```
NSString *strToSet = textbox.text;

[view.label setText:strToSet];

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

---

This use to work for me before storyboard mode. I Should note that the storyboard contains the tab bar controller which is initially loaded and then I added the additional UIViewController.

The view disappears properly and the tab bar view is visible, but the label does not change. I debugged an verified the string that I am trying to assign to the label has a value and it does. It just seems like everything works except for applying the text to the label.

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong with my method or explain the ideal way of doing this since this is probably the wrong way to go about it.

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at a guess, it's probably taking a snapshot image of the modal view and animating that off. try something like:

```
- (void)dismissModal {
  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

....

```
  NSString *strToSet = textbox.text;
  [view.label setText:strToSet];
  [self performSelector:@selector(dismissModal) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
```

Comment: i made these changes but it still isn't applying the text from the string to the label on the tab bar controller view. It still dismisses the view properly though

Comment: hmm, odd. if you change the 0.1 to, say, 1.0 does it still not work? what happens if you set the label without calling the dismiss - does it change then?

Answer (score 0):

Your need to setup a delegate protocol which would allow the one view controller to write data back to one of the other view controller. Read Understanding [Fundamental Design Patterns](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/02_DesignPatterns.html).

I've searched for a tutorial for you that explains how to implement a delegate design pattern. There are a number of steps involved to make it work. [This](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/81489-how-why-implement-delegation-pattern.html) tutorial contains all the steps.